# creating a Database's Collation from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

I need to create by variable the collate or change it after creating database to 
so t tried this :

```
USE master;  
GO  
IF DB_ID (N'DATA') IS NOT NULL  
DROP DATABASE DATA;  
GO  
DECLARE @COLLATE Nvarchar(50) SET  @COLLATE ='Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC'
CREATE DATABASE DATA  
COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC;  
--COLLATE @COLLATE; 
GO 

SELECT name, collation_name  
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE name = N'DATA';  

--or
ALTER DATABASE [DATA]  COLLATE @COLLATE 

SELECT name, collation_name  
FROM sys.databases  
WHERE name = N'DATA';
```

Comment: Your best bet is dynamic SQL

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis Can you please explain me how do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a SQL script what you can use

```
USE master;  
GO  
IF DB_ID (N'DATA') IS NOT NULL  
DROP DATABASE DATA;  
GO  
DECLARE @COLLATE Nvarchar(50) 
SET @COLLATE ='Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC'

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'CREATE DATABASE DATA COLLATE ' + @COLLATE; 
exec sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

Please be careful, since it runs a DROP database command

For more on [building dynamic SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx) you can review mentioned article